# SKAction Playsound not working

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, ios8

I'm trying to add sound effects to my game using SKActions, the app runs perfectly excepts that the sound doesn't play. This is the code I am using:

```
    SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Pop.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Comment: Pop.mp3 filename is exactly that with uppercase P? Note that if this is a short sound effect it ought to be .wav/.caf

Comment: Yes its Pop with Upper case. But I will change to wav.